# Correct way to access the USERPROFILE dir of a specific user in a script?

Tags: powershell, profile

I'm writing a script to perform some file operations in the USERPROFILE folder of each (local) user on a Windows machine.

I have found various examples that use `$env:USERPROFILE` to identify the profile directory of the current logged-in user. I have also seen examples that assume all user profiles are saved in C:\Users\ and iterate/filter over that folder.

However, profile folders can be moved on Windows. My aim is to find (robustly) the profile directory of a specific user, given either that user's username (string) or a LocalUser object.

I can get an array of User objects based on active accounts with-

```
$users = Get-LocalUser | Where-Object Enabled -eq true
```

But the properties of those LocalUser objects are limited, and the UserProfile path is not among them. I believe this information is stored in the registry. I've through the PowerShell docs multiple times, but I haven't yet found the correct incantation that will give me the path of a user profile for a given user, which I can use in a loop to iterate across all users and their profile folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the ***root (parent) directory* of all user profile directories** from the registry as follows:

```bash
$profilesRootDir = 
  Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' ProfilesDirectory
```

To get **a *specific user's* profile directory**, say `jdoe`, you can then use:

```bash
# See more robust alternative below.
Join-Path $profilesRootDir jdoe
```

However, the **ultimate source of truth is the `ProfileImagePath` value in the *subkeys* of the above registry key path**, **named for each user's *SID*** (security identifier), which **[`Get-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser)** *does* provide (the output objects have a `.SID` property).

Thus, it is **better** to use:

```bash
Get-ItemPropertyValue "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$((Get-LocalUser jdoe).SID)" ProfileImagePath
```

To reliably get the **profile directories of *all enabled* local users**, use the following:

```bash
Get-LocalUser | 
  Where-Object Enabled |
  ForEach-Object {
    # Note the use of ...\ProfileList\$($_.SID) and value name ProfileImagePath
    Get-ItemPropertyValue "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$($_.SID)" ProfileImagePath
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something along this line:

```
$users = Get-LocalUser | Where-Object Enabled -eq true

$profilesRootDir = @(
 Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' ProfilesDirectory)

ForEach ($User in $Users) {

  $UserPath = Join-Path -Path "$profilesRootDir" -ChildPath "$User"

  "User     : $User`n" +
  "User-Path: $UserPath" 
}
```

Output:

```
User     : Bruce
User-Path: C:\Users\Bruce
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wmi class win32_userprofile, but it only has sid, not username:

```
get-wmiobject win32_userprofile | select sid,localpath

sid                                              localpath
---                                              ---------
S-1-5-21-3961843708-1234567890-2901110831-1002   C:\Users\user
```